# Return 2 or more values using map(function ($data) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, algolia

I cannot find the way. Im using the following [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/laravel/relationships/) option to create a relationship.

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $array = $this->toArray();

    $array['categories'] = $this->categories->map(function ($data) {
                             return $data['name'];
                           })->toArray();

   return $array;
}
```

Despite I read php page for [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) I cannot find the way to return more than one value, as an example:

```
function ($data) {{return $data['name']; return $data['value'] ;})->toArray(),
```

gives no error but no output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$array['categories'] = $this->categories->map(function ($data) {
                         return [$data['name'], $data['value']];
                       })->toArray();
```

You can return an `array` instead of trying to return 2 `strings`.